# Tenserflow hangs when running inference with GPU enabled

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am new to AI and TensorFlow and I am trying to use the TensorFlow object detection API on windows. 
My current goal is to do real time human detection in a video stream. 
For this I modified a python example from the TensorFlow Model Garden (https://github.com/tensorflow/models).
At the moment it detects all objects (not just humans) and shows the bounding boxes using opencv.

It works fine when I have the GPU disabled (os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1")
But when I enable the GPU and start the script it will hang on the first frame.

Output:

```
2020-04-22 16:00:53.597492: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:56.942141: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:56.976635: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 960M computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.176GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2020-04-22 16:00:56.989129: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.000622: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.012247: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.020575: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.031536: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.042564: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.066289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:57.075760: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-22 16:00:59.239211: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-04-22 16:00:59.256577: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1f3f73cd670 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-22 16:00:59.264241: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-04-22 16:00:59.272280: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 960M computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.176GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2020-04-22 16:00:59.281409: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.288204: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.293112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.298222: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.305446: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.310590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.316250: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-22 16:00:59.324588: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-22 16:01:00.831569: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-22 16:01:00.839147: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0
2020-04-22 16:01:00.842279: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N
2020-04-22 16:01:00.846140: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1024 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-04-22 16:01:00.865546: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1f39174cba0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-22 16:01:00.873656: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 960M, Compute Capability 5.0
[<tf.Tensor 'image_tensor:0' shape=(None, None, None, 3) dtype=uint8>]
2020-04-22 16:01:10.876733: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-22 16:01:11.814909: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
2020-04-22 16:01:11.852909: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-22 16:01:12.149312: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.04GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.179484: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.04GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.209036: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.06GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.237205: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.05GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.266147: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.09GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.295182: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.08GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.325645: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.357550: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.405332: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.14GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-04-22 16:01:12.436336: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:245] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.27GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import pathlib

if "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
  while "models" in pathlib.Path.cwd().parts:
    os.chdir('..')

import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

import cv2 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# patch tf1 into `utils.ops`
utils_ops.tf = tf.compat.v1

# Patch the location of gfile
tf.gfile = tf.io.gfile

# os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

def load_model(model_name):
  base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
  model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
  model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname=model_name, 
    origin=base_url + model_file,
    untar=True)

  model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

  model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))
  model = model.signatures['serving_default']

  return model

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'models/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
# model_name= 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_08';
detection_model = load_model(model_name)

print(detection_model.inputs)

detection_model.output_dtypes
detection_model.output_shapes

def run_inference_for_single_image(model, image):
    image = np.asarray(image)
    # The input needs to be a tensor, convert it using `tf.convert_to_tensor`.
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
    # The model expects a batch of images, so add an axis with `tf.newaxis`.
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis,...]

    # Run inference (it hangs here)
    output_dict = model(input_tensor)

    # All outputs are batches tensors.
    # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
    # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
    num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
    output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
    output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections

    # detection_classes should be ints.
    output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

    # Handle models with masks:
    if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        # Reframe the the bbox mask to the image size.
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(output_dict['detection_masks'], output_dict['detection_boxes'],image.shape[0], image.shape[1])      
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(detection_masks_reframed > 0.5,tf.uint8)
        output_dict['detection_masks_reframed'] = detection_masks_reframed.numpy()

    return output_dict

def show_inference(model):
    # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
    # result image with boxes and labels on it.
    ret, image_np = cap.read()

    #percent by which the image is resized
    #scale_percent = 30

    #calculate the 50 percent of original dimensions
    #width = int(image_np.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    #height = int(image_np.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)

    # dsize
    #dsize = (width, height)

    # resize image
    #image_np = cv2.resize(image_np, dsize)

    # Actual detection.
    output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)

    # Visualization of the results of a detection.
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))

while True:
  show_inference(detection_model)
  if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

I have installed the following versions:
Python: 3.7 64 bit 
Tensorflow: 2.2.0-rc3 
Cuda: 10.1 
cudnn 7.6.5.32

I tried this on 2 different machines:
Machine 1:
 - CPU: i7-6700HQ
 - RAM: 16 GB
 - GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

Machine 2:
 - CPU: i5-6400 
 - RAM: 16 GB
 - GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960

I am not sure how to debug this. I tried the same code on two different machine and the result was almost the same. 
The only difference was the time it took for it to hang. Machine 1 would hang immediately and machine 2 took roughly 30 seconds. 
Machine 2 was able to process the video and detect object up until the hang.

I looked into the 'Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory' warnings.  
I tried some options that limited the available GPU memory size, but this did not help.

There where also multiple posts that sugested reducing the batch size.  
My interpretation was that this was only helpful when training your own model.  
And because I am using pre-trained models, this was not applicable.

I also tried to use different models: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17 and faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2017_11_08. Both models have the same result.

The last thing I tried was to reduce the image size before processing it. This also did not help.

Any help would be much appreciated

**Update**
I also tried it on a RTX2070 super GPU. There are no warnings about memory allocation. This is also not able to complete a single inference. 
Just for completeness, this is the console output [The text 'inference start' is printed before running the inference. If the inference would complete, it would print 'inference end']:

```
2020-04-24 11:30:16.579805: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.916146: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.941805: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-04-24 11:30:18.946134: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.951172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.954809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.957258: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.961662: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.965553: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.978671: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.980998: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-24 11:30:18.982226: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-04-24 11:30:18.984167: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.785GHz coreCount: 40 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-04-24 11:30:18.987291: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.988809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.990303: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.991792: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.993320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.996960: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:18.998497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:19.000191: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-24 11:30:19.430864: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-24 11:30:19.433076: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0
2020-04-24 11:30:19.434566: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N
2020-04-24 11:30:19.436400: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6281 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
[<tf.Tensor 'image_tensor:0' shape=(None, None, None, 3) dtype=uint8>]
inference start
2020-04-24 11:30:24.728554: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-04-24 11:30:25.608426: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2020-04-24 11:30:25.625904: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
```

**Update 2**
When Eager mode is disabled everything runs fine (even on GPU), but then I am not able to retreive the found objects.
The next thing I tried was running it with sessions (like TensorFlow 1 I think). Here the function session.run() blocks indefinitely on GPU. And again on CPU it works fine.

Comment: Hi, just a suggestion. Maybe you could try your code on Google Colab with the device set to GPU (and maybe one image uploaded to Colab). They provide free access to at least K40 with 12 GB memory which should be enough for inference. If it works, you know it is a memory problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I will try to get it to work there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GPU try to install tensorflow-gpu. The tensorflow you are using seems based on the documentation to support GPU but you can try and specify is implicitly. Try this on a python virtual environment first.

```
    pip uninstall tensorflow
```

uninstall tensorflow-gpu: (make sure to run this even if you are not sure if you installed it)

```
    pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
```

Install specific tensorflow-gpu version:

```
    pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0
```

Comment: I am using TensorFlow 2. What I understood from the documentation this already includes the GPU support (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). 
From Tensorflow 1.15 and older there is a separate gpu install.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using GPU?  You get the below message when enabling GPU :

Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

while it works fine only on CPU.

Comment: I uninstalled tensorflow and installed tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0. Like you suggested. 
I am also new to pip and python. I install things using : 
python -m pip install .....
Does that matter?

Anyway, I ran the code again and now it is stuck at the line: 'model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))'


The terminal output looked similar to what I had before.
So maybe way I am using the models is wrong? The current way is based on the example in the object detection API. It downloads a model from a server, and then uses it.

Comment: I think that is ok as long as you don't have various python versions installed. You can always check with python --version , python3 --version .

What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: I forgot to close the previous hang, and it turns out it just took a long time (a few minutes) to load the model the first time (not sure why). When I run it now it loads in about a second. It does however still get stuck while running the inference. I get 10 processed frames and then it stops. I let it hang for a while (maybe this is a single time event) but so far (2 minutes of waiting) it is still stuck. 

I don't get any error, it just hangs for ever.

Comment: In this case, can you add some logging info or print a statement and see what it says? Maybe also your terminal output.

Comment: The problem is that the hang occurs inside a TensorFlow library function (I placed print statements around the function call). And as far as I can tell, I can not increase the verbosity level further than default (shows Info, Warning and Error messages). I was hoping for a Debug verbosity level.
So either I will have to add prints to the library sources (not sure how yet) or use a TensorFlow debugger (one of these maybe: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/debugging-tensorflow-a-starter-e6668ce72617/). Or are there better ways of doing this?
My terminal output is in the question above.

Comment: Did you install this libraries? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/requirements.txt

Comment: I ran https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/setup.py to install it. 
This only installs a few items from your list. 
The example I used was also from the research folder (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)
I can try to install the other packages. I would however expect an error and stop of execution if a package was missing. 
I also noticed that the example requires the pycocotools package. Unfortunately I get some errors installing it. I will try to do this monday.

Comment: I was looking at the master.

Have you followed this instructions? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Comment: From the instructions I only missed the pycocotools. After some googling I managed to install this aswell. But it still does not work. 
At the end of the instructions there is a test, which fails for me. Error: "cannot import name 'anchor_generator_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' ". I checked and this file is in object_detection\protos. I am going to try and get this to run

Comment: I went back to TensorFlow version 1.15. Here Eager execution is disabled by default, en then it runs fine. 
If I then enable eager execution, it hangs after a few frames. 
I don't understand what it does yet, but I am hoping I can run it without eager execution enabled.